# How to use imdbpy using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, imdb, imdbpy

I am using imdbpy to get the ratings of movies.I have succesfully installed the imdbpy but running into problem while running this small code.
here is the code:

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
the_matrix = ia.get_movie('0133093')
print the_matrix['director']
```

error:

```
from imdb import IMDb
ImportError: cannot import name IMDb
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you give the full error trace?
One of the reasons could be that you might have saved this code in the file `imdb.py` which would be shadowing the original `imdb` module and that's why python can no longer import `IMDb`.

Comment: **Here is the full error**:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "F:\Pyht\Projects\imdb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from imdb import IMDb
    File "F:\Pyht\Projects\imdb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from imdb import IMDb
    ImportError: cannot import name IMDb

Comment: As you can see from path ``F:\Pyht\Projects\imdb.py`` file name is ``imdb.py``. Just change it to some other name and it should work fine.

Comment: Great, you saved me.